# TypeError: this is undefined on setstate reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

can anyone help me or give me solution to get value of

"position.coords.latitude"

i want that value update this.state "city" after user click button

```
class Home extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        city: '',
        lats : '',
        long : ''
    }
    this.Kirim = this.Kirim.bind(this)
}

Kirim() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(Position){
            this.setState({ city:position.coords.latitude}) // erorr here
        })

      } else { 

      } 
}

render(){
    let {city} = this.state
    console.log(city)
    return(

        <Fragment>
            <div className="form-add">
                <button onClick={this.Kirim}>Kirim</button>
            </div>
        </Fragment>

    )
}
```

}

Comment: You have Position in returned data, but use position in assignment.

Comment: thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an arrow function `() => {}` instead of regular function.

When using `function`, `this` will be the function's `this`.

When using arrow function, it will be the component's `this`, which has `setState`.

Change

```
// normal function
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(Position) {
    this.setState({ city:position.coords.latitude}) // error here
})
```

to

```
// arrow function 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.setState({ city:position.coords.latitude}) // error here
})
```

Comment: thank you very much... you save my time

Comment: Why down vote if the answer is correct?

Comment: i dont know i just want to push correct button.. maybe bug in my pc

Answer (score 0):

Change onClick={this.Kirim} to "onClick={() => this.Kirim()}, and position.coords.latitude to Position.coords.latitude. From where do you get navigator?

Comment: sorry my bad... that code is wrong

Comment: He binds the function in the constructor though, so the `onClick={}` shouldn't matter. [`navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator) is a global object.